# GSON: Unknown element FloatToByteBufferAdapted

Tags: java, android, gson, object-to-string

So im trying to save an object with GSON, when I save it it's all OK, but when I try to load it GSON is returning

```
    03-26 19:27:19.774: E/AndroidRuntime(32179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-26 19:27:19.774: E/AndroidRuntime(32179): com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Unknown element type: FloatToByteBufferAdapter
    03-26 19:27:19.774: E/AndroidRuntime(32179):    at         com.uraniumdevelopers.etchcubes.FloatBufferAdapter.deserialize(FloatBufferAdapter.java:27)...
```

The whole stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/qJ2SvZwS

I pasted the code on pastebin, because it's big and unreadable(I posted the codes after pastebin.com/ ):

MainActivity:29wu8cnT

FloatBufferAdapter:C5pcu2Tq

The class I'm trying to save:

RenderNode:K1TmXJdw

Cube(used in RenderNode):DTKrUYTM

Thanks for the help in forward, I really need to fix this.

Comment: No, post relevant code here.

Comment: but it gets all screwed up

Comment: Then format it. If you don't know how, go through the Help Center. Only post relevant code.

Comment: the point is i cant get FloatBuffer to desirialize properly

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this error because you're trying to convert the `FloatToByteBufferAdapter` object to JSON, and one of the properties is not being converted properly, or is of a type that cannot be converted.  You can exclude properties of the object you're converting (I assume the a property of the `FloatToByteBufferAdapter` object).

see the documentation on "Excluding Fields From Serialization and Deserialization" here: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide